# NDK OpenSL ES looping sound with a buffer queue

Tags: android, android-ndk, opensl

I'm using SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue for all audio files.
It works good, but...
It doesnt support seek and loop.

> OpenSL can't require SL_IID_SEEK with a buffer queue data source

How can i use looping for files? Cant use streaming - low latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, this is not possible with `SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue`.
Had to use `SLDataLocator_AndroidFD`...

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with buffer queue Enqueue function on player callback function.

the sample code like this...

```
struct PARAM { char* buffer;  long  size; };

void bqPlayerCallback(SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf bqPlayerBufferQueue, void *context)
{
    ...
    PARAM* param = (PARAM*)context;
    result = (*bqPlayerBufferQueue)->Enqueue(bqPlayerBufferQueue, param->buffer, nparam->size);
}

void createAudioPlayer... {
    (*engineEngine)->CreateAudioPlayer(engineEngine, &bqPlayerObject, ...);
    ...
    PARAM* param = new PARAM{buffer, size};
    result = (*bqPlayerBufferQueue)->RegisterCallback(bqPlayerBufferQueue, bqPlayerCallback, param);
}
```